# Not able to change literal text after postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

VB

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If Me.IsPostBack Then
tb.Text = Request.Form("ctl00$cphContent$tb").ToString()
    End If
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text) Then
                lit.Text = "Not Empty"
            Else
                lit.Text = "Empty"
                End If
End Sub
```

ASP

```
<asp:Literal ID="lit" runat="server"></asp:Literal> 
<asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="click me" />
```

If I call the page for the first time, the literal.text is 'empty'. Than I set one breakpoint to lit.Text = "Not Empty". After I type something in the textbox and click the button the Element at the breakpoint shows me that the lit.Text is now "Not Empty". All fine.....But the lit.Text on the page are still "empty" and not "Not Empty".....Why? I'm not able to change the lit.Text.

Regards

Comment: Why are you changing the `TextBox`' `Text` property in `Page_Init` according to the value of `Request.Form("ctl00$cphContent$tb")`? Why are you doing this in `Page_Init` at all and not in `Page_Load`? I assume this is a ViewState issue.

Comment: The problem are the Page_Init. In Page_Load it works fine. But I dont know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are modifying the values during the `Page_Init` event. Try modifying it in or after `Page_Load`.

Read up on the [ASP.net Page LifeCycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). When you set the value in `Page_Init`, after this happens, in the control's ViewState is loaded, and this set's the control's value back to 'Empty'.